# How can I assert that a map has the values needed?

Tags: apex, unit-test, map

if anyone could help; I'd appreciate some guidance on a test class I am working on. I am new to Apex and I am trying to test a class that uses a map which is the only piece of code I need testing for.

I am receiving 3 errors which are likely to surround the same issue but am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

> Error:Expecting '}' but was: 'System.assertEquals'
>   Error:Unreachable statement
>   Error:Extra '', at '}'.

```
@isTest
private inherited sharing class FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper_Test
{
   static Map<String, String> getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest()
   {
      return new Map<String, String>
      {
        'Previous_wall_repair_photo__c' => 'Previous_Wall_Repair_Notes__c',
        'LeaningBowing_Wall_Photo__c'   => 'Leaning_Bowing_Wall_Notes__c',
        'Floor_Crack_Repair_Photo__c'   => 'Floor_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Wall_Crack_Photo__c'           => 'Wall_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Shallow_Footing_Photo__c'      => 'Shallow_Footing_Photo_Notes__c'
      };

      System.assertEquals(5, getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest().values().size());
   }
}
```

So you can see, I 'think' I have the class structured properly and to me the assert statement even looks good. What is going on?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish? Currently your unit test just seems to be inspecting its own behavior, but a unit test is supposed to run live code and then verify results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Hello,

The problem IS the structure.

Let's analyze your code.

You have a test class called : FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper_Test
In this class you have a method called getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest and I suppose it's a test method so you should have @test also on it. (Point of attention 1)

you have your return statement before the assert ==> the assert will be unreachable (compilation error) (Point of attention 2)

Let's correct all that :)

```
@isTest
private inherited sharing class FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper_Test
{
   static Map<String, String> getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest()
   {
      return new Map<String, String>
      {
        'Previous_wall_repair_photo__c' => 'Previous_Wall_Repair_Notes__c',
        'LeaningBowing_Wall_Photo__c'   => 'Leaning_Bowing_Wall_Notes__c',
        'Floor_Crack_Repair_Photo__c'   => 'Floor_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Wall_Crack_Photo__c'           => 'Wall_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Shallow_Footing_Photo__c'      => 'Shallow_Footing_Photo_Notes__c'
      };

   }

   @istest private static void testMethod1() {
      System.assertEquals(5, getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest().values().size());
   }
}
```

Now let's talk best practice.

You should separate your code logic and the test class.
So to do this in a clean way, you should have two classes:

Classe1: (not a test class)

```
private inherited sharing class FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper
{
   public static Map<String, String> getPhotoNotesFieldMap()
   {
      return new Map<String, String>
      {
        'Previous_wall_repair_photo__c' => 'Previous_Wall_Repair_Notes__c',
        'LeaningBowing_Wall_Photo__c'   => 'Leaning_Bowing_Wall_Notes__c',
        'Floor_Crack_Repair_Photo__c'   => 'Floor_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Wall_Crack_Photo__c'           => 'Wall_Crack_Notes__c',
        'Shallow_Footing_Photo__c'      => 'Shallow_Footing_Photo_Notes__c'
      };

   }

}
```

class 2: (Test Class)

```
@isTest
private inherited sharing class FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper_TEST
{
   @istest private static void testMethod1() {
      System.assertEquals(5, FLLC_Foreman_Job_Packet_Helper.getPhotoNotesFieldMap().values().size());
   }
}
```

Hope it could help you :)

Regards

Comment: OMG you just literally solved my problem. Thank you for the time you took to help me out with this. This is exactly what I needed. Kudos to you man!

Answer (score 2):

1. Nothing can be written after return statement.
2. Methods with @IsTest annotation should be void.

What I suggest you to do.
Move method getPhotoNotesFieldMap to the separate class, remove Test from method name.

In your test class set ethod:

```
@IsTest
static void getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest()
{
    Map<String, String> toCheck = YourNewClass.getPhotoNotesFieldMap();

    System.assertEquals(5, toCheck.values().size());
}
```

Comment: You are just checking size? Not the values needed?#

Comment: I need to technically check both.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Okay so I made changes per your instructions and things seem to be validating fine but running the test I am now approached with this error:

Method getPhotoNotesFieldMapTest does not exist in the the apex class with Id :01p8A000000nB5p